# Adding a coloured text box

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to add a coloured text box and icon to my SharePoint classic web page. Exactly like the image below (but a different colour text box)

Thank you :)

[image]

Comment: You can use Content editor web part with Bootstrap and CSS to show such textboxes.

Comment: Be careful with applying Bootstrap. Bootstrap will redefine inbuilt SharePoint styles, for example box-sizing:border-box; instead of SharePoint box-sizing:content-box;

Answer (score 2):

The solution is:

1. Upload icon in SharePoint library or copy link to existing SharePoint standard icon
2. Build html markup with styles
3. Add script editor or content editor web part into your SharePoint classic web page
4. Put your html code into web part

Answer (score 1):

Sample demo, update the image and CSS accordingly.

[image]

[image]

Insert the custom HTML code.

```
<style>
        .inline-block {
   display: inline-block;
}
    </style>
    <div style="background-color:#e2d3f1">
        <div>
            <img class="inline-block" width="25" height="25" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-warning-icon.png">
            <h3 class="inline-block">Note</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
            I am trying to add a coloured text box and icon to my SharePoint classic web page. Exactly like the image below (but a different colour text box)
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

[image]